# How to combine to php's (sql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to combine these two codes,more likely the sql. I'm sitting on it about hours and can't get it.

```
<?php
$mysqli2 = new mysqli("Edudb", "mct", "QwSkepticx97!");
$mysqli2->select_db("maturita");
$ask2 = $mysqli2->query("SELECT * FROM gallery");
if(mysqli_num_rows($ask2)>0)
{   
while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_object($ask2)) 
{   
echo "<a href='show-gall.php?gallery=$row2->gall_id'>$row2->name<br></a</span>";
}
}       
?>
```

and this one

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("Edudb", "mct", "QwSkepticx97!", "maturita");
$sql="SELECT g.name, i.img_thumb FROM gallery g JOIN images i ON g.gall_id = i.gall_id GROUP BY g.gall_id ";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
{   
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($query)) 
{
    echo "<div class='view'>";
    echo "<a href='show-gall.php?gallery=$row->gall_id'><img src='$row->img_thumb' alt=''></a>";
    echo "<br/>";   
    echo "<a href='show-gall.php?gallery=$row->gall_id'>$row->name</a>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "</div>";
 }
}   
?>
```

I'll be thankful for any suggestions

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Combine in what sense? What's the expected result?

Comment: What is the problem? What are you having trouble with? Reuse the database connection, no need to declare that twice, and run two separate queries. What's the problem?

Comment: The first sql get into the second code.

Comment: ...aren't you doing that already?

Comment: I thougt but when i click on the link the id of the gallery is missing

Comment: `?gallery` you need a GET array for that and you're most likely looking for pagination

Comment: You need to add `g.gall_id` in the second query. Right now, you're only fetching: `g.name, i.img_thumb `. Just add all the columns you need in your SELECT and you'll be set.

Comment: Nope a need on the site ......show-gall.php?gallery=5. I m getting it in the first code. but in the second just ...show-gall.php?gallery= . And i need that id and dont know how to get insert the sql into second code.

Comment: Change `SELECT g.name, i.img_thumb FROM` to `SELECT g.gall_id, g.name, i.img_thumb FROM`. Like I said in my previous comment, just declare the columns you want to fetch...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yey! Thanks man!

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
include('here put the name of one file of two ');
```

Then put this statement in the other one.
Now the other file that has include() statement shows everything in the second one.